# Trace.TraceWarning source name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, logging, nlog

If I just call `System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceWarning("...")` what is the `source` string that a trace listener should be configured in the config to pick up?  I see all kinds of documentation on explicit `TraceSource` but I can't find what this default is for the `Trace` static.  In my immediate situation, traces will emitted from a separate assembly, a dependency of the executable.

I'm tempted to think it will default to the assembly name but I'm not confident in that.  It is clunky to attempt and discover and I might have to make some different decisions.

[image]

Comment: If we were talking about connection strings in web.config it would pick up the one from where the “main” app resides..

Answer (score 0):

`System.Diagnostics.Trace` writes to the listeners defined in the `trace` xml config element :

```
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
            <listeners>
                <add name="file" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\tracelog.log" />            
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```